Windows 11: DISM Error 0x800f081f - Source Files Could Not Be Found During Offline Repair
I'm facing an issue on Windows 11 Professional with the SFC command.
I ran: sfc /scannow, and the result was:
"Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them." The log file details are available at: C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log.
Following that, I ran the DISM command:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
This produced the following error:
Error: 0x800f081f - The source files could not be found.
To repair the image, I downloaded a Windows 11 ISO, mounted it, (Index 6, Windows 11 Pro) to my local machine for an offline repair. /LimitAccess is used due to the machine is not connected to the internet:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:E:\Sources\install.wim:6 /limitaccess
But I still encountered the same error: The source file could not be found.
I then copied the install.wim file to a folder on my local D: drive, gave full write permissions to the folder (Created Windows 11 Folder), and ran the following command:
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:D:\Windows11\Sources\install.wim:6 /limitaccess
However, I continue to receive the error:
Error: 0x800f081f - The source files could not be found.
I also tried using the new Windows 11 image with install.esd file from the Windows 11 ISO instead of install.wim, but encountered the same error.
I also tried:
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup
dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup /resetbase
commands but the issue persists.
I used the same procedure on a Windows 10 machine, and it worked perfectly. This problem only occurs on Windows 11.
Does anyone have advice on how to resolve this issue for Windows 11 in an offline environment?
Any help would be appreciated!

Generate an ISO for the latest build of Windows using UUP Dump and perform an in-place upgrade. After the system has finished upgrading, clean up the component store (WinSxS Folder) of your Windows installation using the /ResetBase switch with the /StartComponentCleanup parameter:
Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase

After the command completes, check the component store's health and verify that no corruptions are detected:
Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth

Now run the SFC command tool to repair your Windows installation.
